# Consistent hashing and redis - how to use te same algo in php and in python

Tags: php, python, sharding, consistent-hashing

In python I use a python lib called hash_ring for sharding keys for redis.  However..I now need a php app and python app to find a shard server given a key.

Is there a consistent hashing library that uses the same underlying algo but has many supported clients such as ruby,php,python etc?

Comment: For memcache I know you want libketama. There might be something similar for redis.

Comment: The author has a [web page where he writes about the implementation of `hash_ring`](http://amix.dk/blog/viewEntry/19367). Basically, it's MD5. Shouldn't be too hard to implement the same algorithm in PHP.